# Grounding a Light Fixture

Tags: electrical, wiring, light-fixture, grounding

I am trying to hook up a new flush mount LED light fixture in my basement.  The existing metal box has the ground wire screwed into it, so there is only a loose white and black wire.  The light fixture has a green ground wire.  There is no bracket for the metal outlet box and one is not required with the light fixture I'm putting in.

So what do I attach the light fixture ground wire to?

[image]

Comment: Can you post a photo looking into the back of the box please?

Comment: Not the actual picture of my metal outlet box, but same idea.  Feeder ground is hooked around screw in metal outlet.

Comment: Can you not get us a photo of the actual box in question?